# Krull topology is discrete if only if the exntension is finite

Tags: galois-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $M/K$ be arbitrary extension.
Then, we can define **Krull topology** on $Gal(M/K)$ by taking {$Gal(M/F)|K⊆F⊆M,[F:K]＜∞$} as fundamental system of neighborhood of $0$.

I guess $Gal(M/K)$ has discrete topology if only if $M/K$ is finite extension, because krull topology is one which is also defined as inverse limit of discrete topological group.

But I want to prove from definition of krull topology.

The condition of krull topology is discrete is equivalent to
$∀σ∈Gal(M/K)$,{$σ$} is open subset.This is equivalent to $∀σ∈Gal(M/K)$,$∃V∈${$σGal(M/K)|K⊆F⊆M$}$,V⊆Gal(M/K)$ from definition of fundamental system of neighborhoods.
But I cannot proceed from here. Why this is equivalent to $M/K$ is finite ?

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that a Galois group is compact, so it is discrete if and only if it is finite?

Comment: Thank you, your perspective is excellent, but I want to prove from definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you really should only be talking about "Galois group" and "Krull topology" when your extension is actually Galois, because the resulting topological group can be very badly behaved otherwise.

For example, if $M/K$ is purely inseparable of infinite degree (e.g. $\mathbb{F}_p(X_n;n\in\mathbb{N})/\mathbb{F}_p(X_n^p;n\in\mathbb{N})$), then $\mathrm{Aut}(M/K)$ is trivial, so necessarily discrete, yet not finite by assumption. Thus, your claim is not true in general.

Now, assume $M/K$ is a Galois extension. Since $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ is a topological group (homogeneous suffices), it is discrete if and only if $\{e\}\subseteq\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ ($e$ is the identity element) is open. By the definition via the fundamental system of neighborhoods, if this is the case, there is an intermediate extension $M/F/K$ finite over $K$, such that $\mathrm{Gal}(M/F)\subseteq\{e\}$. Since $e\in\mathrm{Gal}(M/F)$, it follows that $\mathrm{Gal}(M/F)=\{e\}$. Since $M^{\{e\}}=M$ trivially and $M^{\mathrm{Gal}(M/F)}=F$ by Galois theory, it follows that $M=F$ is finite over $K$. The converse is hopefully clear.

Comment: The converse is, For arbitrary element $x∈$ $Gal(M/K)$, {$x$}$＝${$xGal(M/F)|K⊆F＝M$}$⊆${$xGal(M/F)|K⊆F⊆M$},thus every single element of $Gal(M/K)$ is open, thus discrete topology, correct ?

Comment: @kleinfour That's somewhat confusingly written, but the essence is right: since $M/K$ is finite, $\mathrm{Gal}(M/M)=\{e\}$ is open by definition, then translate to get that $\{x\}$ is open for all $x\in\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$.

Comment: Is your second line of the proof ⊆  correct ? I think {e}⊆Gal is obvious because galois group is a group.. I should have misunderstand something about your notation.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to finish that sentence. Will fix.